# Reading emulated NFC tag (pn71501) using IDTronic Evo HF or ACS ACR1252U

Tags: nfc, rfid, acr1252

I have a device that is emulating nfc tag using pn71501 chip. I don't know how exactly code works in that device but what I definitely know this chip can emulate tag using only ISO14443 standard. So both my readers can read this type of tags but by some reason I can read from this device is UID, nothing else. As I know reading memory from tag with ISO 14443 requires block authentication but it doesn't help for me. For reading tags using IDtronic EVO HF I use software downloaded from here: https://download.idtronic.de/Card%20Reader/Card%20Reader%20HF%20SET%20SDK.zip
For ACS ACR1252U I tried many different apps including my own apps and none of them could read it.
Interesting fact is that android and ios devices can read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PN7150.pdf) for that chip it says "PN7150 does not support a complete card protocol. This has to be handled by the host controller"

So the chip itself might not be doing any more than than ISO 14443 A-3 and B-2 parts which really only includes the Anticollision and UID and then storing/transmitting data is handled by the host controller using the higher level protocol parts.

Also the free software you get with card readers tend to be very basic and just reads the UID for inventory purposes, you have to write your own software if you want to do more with these readers and they usually like the [ACR1252U](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6402/API-ACR1252U-1.16.pdf) have a datasheet on how to do this.

So the question is what is the host controller attached to the NCF chip doing and software it is running?

**Update based on comments**

I would assume that host controller does implement one of the higher level protocols for a Type 3 or 4 Tag (most likely Type 4)

The you just need to write a program for the USB readers to correctly issue the right commands to read the right type 3 or 4 Tag.

As noted the Android (or Iphone) "Taginfo" App from NXP implements reading using the Type 3 and 4 protocols, so this should tell you what the Tag is behaving as and the you can write the software for the USB readers to match.

[Type 3 and 4 specifications](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/)

Comment: I don't really know what hardware is installed but I can guess that host controller is octavo osd3358. Could it be like that? Also i don't what software it is running, i only got that device and I have to make it work with at least one of this readers. As i think it has linux core, but I don't know exact software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if it is not problem for you could you send link to some refence or some link where i can read about it. I only know basic APDU commands that are listed in acr1252u API pdf file. I tried some of them i thought could help me but none of them worked for me. Is there any chat where i can write directly to you if it is not problem for you? What do you think is it possible to make script for IDTronic Evo HF cause i have it right now?

Comment: NXP offers data-sheets for all their tags: https://www.docstore.nxp.com ...there's [PN7150](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10936.pdf) and [PN7150X](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/nfc-readers/high-performance-nfc-controller-ic-with-support-for-apple-enhanced-contactless-polling-ecp:PN7150X), but no PN71501, therefore I'd question the validity of the model's name. That "PN71501" one can only found on Ali Express - and they might also offer the documentation.

Comment: A lot of "PN71501" listed on places like Ali Express are also listed as "PN7150B0HN/C11002Y" which is an NXP part number as they do come in a variety of packaging formats but the "PN71501" is just what is screen printed on the limited space on the actual chip but are from the ""PN7150" family.